# How to pass data from server to service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to pass data from my server to a service worker, but the data is coming empty to the service worker.

Here is my code:

```
var webpush = require('web-push');
var message = sendData.message;
var subscription_info = sendData.subscription_info;




webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:xxx',
  public_key,
  private_key
);

webpush.setGCMAPIKey('xxx');
webpush.sendNotification(subscription_info, String(message));
```

This is console.log(message):

```
{ text: 'message',
  title: 'title',
  icon_image: 'http://google.com/xxx.jpg',
  link: 'www.google.com' }
```

And this is my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

  var title = event.data.title;
  var options = {
    body: event.data.text,
    requireInteraction: true
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

But title is not being recognized. How can I pass data from my server to the service worker?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code on NodeJS side. you are missing to convert the JSON message object to Buffer (binary).

```
var webpush = require('web-push');
var message = sendData.message;
var subscription_info = sendData.subscription_info;

webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:xxx',
  <Vapid public key>,
  <Vapid private key>
);

webpush.setGCMAPIKey('xxx');
message = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)); // missing code.
webpush.sendNotification(subscription_info, String(message));
```

And In Service worker while subscribing, you need to send encrypted public key with sending subscription request and use that  to send the push notification from server.

```
const vapidPublicKey = '<Vapid public key>';
const convertedVapidKey = urlBase64ToUint8Array(vapidPublicKey);

registration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true, //Always show notification when received
    applicationServerKey: convertedVapidKey
})
.then(function (subscription) {
    console.log(subscription) // use this subscription info on server side
    console.info('Push notification subscribed.');
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Push notification subscription error: ', error);
});
```

**PS. Your public key should be same on server and client side.**